# return this returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, object, ecmascript-6

I have a helper method called magnitude that I tried to use chaining functions with it.

That is my magnitude.js:

```
export const Magnitude = props => {
   let data;

    const formatterObj = {
        getData: props => {
            return data ? data : { ...props, magnitude: '', negativeSign: '', format: '' };
        },
        setData: newData => {
            data = { ...data, ...newData };
        },
        format: str => {
            const { value } = data;
            const absValue = Number(Math.abs(value));
            const negativeSign = value > 0 ? '' : '-';
             const magnitude = (absValue) => { return {value: absValue/10, abbr: 'k'}};

            formatterObj.setData({ value: magnitude.value, magnitude: magnitude.abbr, negativeSign, format: str });
            return this;
         }
    };

    data = formatterObj.getData(props);

    return formatterObj;
};
```

and this is my app.js:

```
 console.log(Magnitude({value: 10000,currency: "$"}).format('NSVU'));
```

I can see on the webkit tool when I debug it that on the return this it is actually return the entire obj including the method format. But when I console.log it prints undefined.

Comment: I made a snippet and immediately got an error here `const magnitude = (absValue) => {
        value: absValue / 10,
        abbr: 'k'
      };` You need to wrap the object: `const magnitude = absValue => ({"value": absValue/10, "abbr": 'k'});`

Comment: Yeah I know I live edited that code to be summarized. Now it is fixed.

Comment: This is shorter: `const magnitude = absValue => ({value: absValue/10, abbr: 'k'});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use parentheses if you wish to return an object from an arrow function.

```
const magnitude = absValue => ({ value: absValue / 10, abbr: "k" });
```

Also, if you wish to return `this` property from `format`, you have to use a normal (ES5-style) function - otherwise the `this` you want is lost due to the lexical binding of the arrow function.

```
format: function(str) {...}
```

Comment: I already answered that in the comment. Perhaps vote for typo close? Or fix the other issue. It does not actually show anything when the brackets are fixed

Comment: Edited @mplungjan - also it's not really a typo.

Comment: Typo-type. It is likely a dupe too

Comment: I fixed it to be with ES5-style and it helped. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries @LilacEilim, always glad to help.

Comment: Yes, always glad to help ;)